# I have a problem with my loop that I couldn't describe

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am new to programming (it's been 1 week) and I made an English thesaurus program which asks you the word you want definition for and pops definitions for that word, and then it loops back to start. When you are asked which word you want a definition for, you can type \exit and stop the program. However it doesn't work in the later stages of the program. For example:

```
Enter a Word or Type (\exit) to Exit: rainn 
Did You Mean 'rain'? (y) for YES and (n) for NO: n
The Word 'rainn' Does Not Exist! Please Try Again: \exit
```

And it prompts here

```
Did You Mean 'exit'? (y) for YES and (n) for NO: n
```

where it should've stopped the program.

Help me I am desperate I tried everything I could.

Here is the code for program:

```py
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

while True:
keyword = input("Enter a Word or Type (\exit) to Exit: ")
    if keyword == "\exit":
        break
    elif keyword.lower() in data:
        output = data[keyword.lower()]
        if isinstance(output, list):
            for definition in output:
                print("\"%s\"" % definition)
        else:
            print("\"%s\"" % definition)
    elif keyword.title() in data:
        output = data[keyword.title()]
        if isinstance(output, list):
            for definition in output:
                print("\"%s\"" % definition)
        else:
            print("\"%s\"" % definition)
    elif keyword.upper() in data:
        output = data[keyword.upper()]
        if isinstance(output, list):
            for definition in output:
                print("\"%s\"" % definition)
        else:
            print("\"%s\"" % definition)
    elif len(get_close_matches(keyword.lower(), data.keys())) > 0:
        correction = input(
            "Did You Mean %s? (y) for YES and (n) for NO: " % (get_close_matches(keyword.lower(), data.keys())[0]).capitalize())
        while True:
            if correction.lower() == "y":
                output = data[get_close_matches(keyword.lower(), data.keys())[0]]
                if isinstance(output, list):
                    for definition in output:
                        print("\"%s\"" % definition)
                else:
                    print("\"%s\"" % definition)
                break
            elif correction.lower() == "n":
                # giving input "\exit" won't work here where it's supposed to
                keyword = input("The Word '%s' Does Not Exist! Please Try Again or Type (\exit) to Exit: " % keyword)
                break
            else:
                correction = input("Unrecognized Input! Please Try Again: ")
    else:
        # giving input "\exit" won't work here too
        keyword = input("The Word '%s' Does Not Exist! Please Try Again or Type (\exit) to Exit: " % keyword)
```

Comment: See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Off-site links are not acceptable.

Comment: @Prune ok I’ll be more careful next time. This is literally my first time asking a question on stack overflow.

Comment: Understood -- we've all been you.  Just repeat the intro tour, pay attention to the "how to ask" and "MRE" sections, and update this appropriately.

Comment: Ok will do when I’m available. Btw what intro tour because I don’t remember any.

Answer (score -1):

This is because when you type '\exit' in the inner while loop and set the keyword variable and it breaks, you then restart at the top of the outer loop and ask for input to set keyword again. So it overwrites the '\exit'. To solve this you can add a flag exit to check if you should ask for input again. Hope this helps! :)

```
import json
from difflib import get_close_matches

data = json.load(open("data.json"))

exit = False
while True:
    if exit != True:
        keyword = input("Enter a Word or Type (\exit) to Exit: ")
    if keyword == "\exit" or exit:
        break
    elif keyword.lower() in data:
        output = data[keyword.lower()]
        if isinstance(output, list):
            for definition in output:
                print("\"%s\"" % definition)
        else:
            print("\"%s\"" % definition)
        break
    elif keyword.title() in data:
        output = data[keyword.title()]
        if isinstance(output, list):
            for definition in output:
                print("\"%s\"" % definition)
        else:
            print("\"%s\"" % definition)
        break
    elif keyword.upper() in data:
        output = data[keyword.upper()]
        if isinstance(output, list):
            for definition in output:
                print("\"%s\"" % definition)
        else:
            print("\"%s\"" % definition)
        break
    elif len(get_close_matches(keyword, data.keys())) > 0:
        correction = input(
            "Did You Mean %s? (y) for YES and (n) for NO: " % (get_close_matches(keyword, data.keys())[0]))
        while True:
            if correction.lower() == "y":
                output = data[get_close_matches(keyword, data.keys())[0]]
                if isinstance(output, list):
                    for definition in output:
                        print("\"%s\"" % definition)
                else:
                    print("\"%s\"" % definition)
                break
            elif correction.lower() == "n":
                # giving input "\exit" won't work here where it's supposed to
                keyword = input("The Word '%s' Does Not Exist! Please Try Again: " % keyword)
                if keyword == "\exit":
                    exit = True
                break
            else:
                correction = input("Unrecognized Input! Please Try Again: ")
    else:
        # giving input "\exit" won't work here too
        keyword = input("The Word '%s' Does Not Exist! Please Try Again: " % keyword)
        if keyword == "\exit":
            exit = True
```

Comment: Yeah man it worked. (Finally!) Thanks so much, I guess I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score -2):

welcome to the world of programming.  It can be frustrating, can't it?

at line 50, you have

```
keyword = input("The Word '%s' Does Not Exist! Please Try Again: " % keyword)
break
```

And the system will wait for input here, but the system never does anything with `keyword`.

I'm not sure what you want the program to do.  I suspect that you want to change that `input` to a `print`, and then start over, allowing the user to enter a new word, or exit the program.

A gentle suggestion for your next question:  it is better to put your code right in the question, rather than make us go find it at another site.  No worries though!  I hope you enjoy your programming adventure.

Comment: Thanks man I’ll take your advices into consideration for next time. For what I want my program to do, I want it to take keyword at line 50 and start over from top. So that if the keyword in line 50 is \end, it will end, if it has a definition, it will print definition and so on.